# Class method accepting lambdas representing functions of various number of argument

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I would like to pass functions in to a generic class method, so the generic class can invoke functions requiring no args, one arg, two args etc.

I have seen variadic templates but I do not like the syntax. A previous SO question recommended passing lambdas, wrapping the function:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48976528/997112

where the answer is:

```
void run_callback(std::function<void()>& func) 
{
    func();
}

run_callback([]{ func_without_params(); });
```

and I therefore added a method which requires no argument:

```
void func_without_params()
{
    std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
}
```

but when I call:

```
run_callback([]{ func_without_params(); });
```

in VS2013 the intellisense detects an error and i get the compiler error:

```
error C2664: 'void run_callback(std::function<void (void)> &)' :
cannot convert argument 1 from
'main::<lambda_de925f4d5cd926a8bb664f9c057a7a19>' to
'std::function<void (void)> &'
```

What is a `main::<lambda_de925f4d5cd926a8bb664f9c057a7a19>` type? I don't fully-understand the error.

Comment: Are you stuck with VS2013?  It's C++11 wasn't great.  2015 update 3 or 2017 have much better support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for evil compiler extensions you cannot initialize a non-const reference (parameter `func`) with something that is not an l-value. Make the parameter const:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void run_callback(std::function<void()> const &func)
{
    func();
}

void func_without_params()
{
    std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    run_callback([] { func_without_params(); });
}
```

Comment: maybe I completely misunderstand the qeustion, but you could pass `func_without_params` directly without using the lambda, no?

Comment: @user463035818 I guess the point of using a lambda is to be able to capture variables to use as parameters for the encapsulated function.

Comment: yes `func_without_params` is just an example for `func_with_any_number_of_params` where the lambda is necessary

Answer (score 1):

> What is a `main::<lambda_de925f4d5cd926a8bb664f9c057a7a19>` type?

What references says about lambda expression:

> The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of unique **unnamed**
>   non-union non-aggregate class type, known as closure type, which is
>   declared **in the smallest block scope**, class scope, or namespace scope
>   that contains the lambda expression.

unnamed only for programmers, compiler knows this name and in your case `lambda_de925f4d5cd926a8bb664f9c057a7a19` is the name of closure type. `main` refers to the function inside which closure type was defined.

You can use [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/) to look behind the scenes. *cppinsights* uses Clang which doesn't accept binding Rvalue to Lvalue reference, so change your code into:

```
void run_callback(std::function<void()> func) // take by value
```

and the output from *cppinsights* is:

```
int main() { // scope of closure type

  class __lambda_14_16 { // closure type
    public: inline /*constexpr */ void operator()() const
    {
      func_without_params();
    }

  };

  run_callback(std::function<void ()>(__lambda_14_16{}));
}
```